# QTable - get QSpinBox & QComboBox value

Tags: python, pyqt

I am having trouble getting the current values from a QTable with QSpinBox & QCOmboBox widgets inserted in the table. I can get the value from Qlineedit, but nothing else except this one widget works. I have tried in several different ways but it keeps returning "None"

[image]

```
class MainWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("ptb")

        # Main frame
        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        # Layout with 2 buttons and a radio button, part of main_layout
        self.horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout()

        self.main_frame_tab_widget = QTabWidget()
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.main_frame_tab_widget)
        self.horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.load_script_button = QPushButton("Load")

        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.load_script_button)

        self.load_script_button.clicked.connect(self.load_script_button_clicked)


        self.main_frame_tab_widget.addTab(self.targeting_tab(), "Targeting")

    def load_script_button_clicked(self):
        model = self.targeting_table.model()
        targeting_table_content = {}
        for row in range(model.rowCount()):
            targeting_table_content[str(model.data(model.index(row, 1)))] = {
                'danger': str(model.data(model.index(row, 2))),
                'loot': str(model.data(model.index(row, 3))),
                'only_if_trapped': str(model.data(model.index(row, 4)))
            }
        print(targeting_table_content)


    def targeting_tab(self):
        targeting_tab = QWidget()

        # Main targeting tab vertical layout, which contains 2 other sublayouts
        targeting_tab_main_layout = QHBoxLayout()

        # Sub vertical layout containing a horizontal layout with 2 buttons and a table bellow the VBox
        inner_left_vertical_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        targeting_tab_main_layout.addLayout(inner_left_vertical_layout)

        # Sub horizontal layout containing 2 buttons
        inner_left_vertical_layouts_sub_horizontal_box = QHBoxLayout()
        inner_left_vertical_layout.addLayout(inner_left_vertical_layouts_sub_horizontal_box)

        # Adding creature
        self.add_creature_button = QPushButton("Add creature")
        inner_left_vertical_layouts_sub_horizontal_box.addWidget(self.add_creature_button)
        self.add_creature_button.clicked.connect(self.add_creature_to_targeting_button_clicked)

        # Deleting creature
        self.delete_creature_button = QPushButton("Delete creature")
        inner_left_vertical_layouts_sub_horizontal_box.addWidget(self.delete_creature_button)
        self.delete_creature_button.clicked.connect(self.delete_creature_button_clicked)

        self.targeting_table = QTableWidget()
        self.targeting_table.setColumnCount(4)
        self.targeting_table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Name', 'Danger', 'Loot', 'Only if trapped'])
        inner_left_vertical_layout.addWidget(self.targeting_table)

        targeting_tab.setLayout(targeting_tab_main_layout)
        return targeting_tab

    def add_creature_to_targeting_button_clicked(self):
        row_count = self.targeting_table.rowCount()
        self.targeting_table.insertRow(row_count)
        self.targeting_table.setItem(row_count, 0, QTableWidgetItem("input_mob_name"))

        self.targeting_table.setCellWidget(row_count, 1, QSpinBox())

        loot_combo_box = QComboBox()
        loot_combo_box.addItems(["Yes", "No"])
        self.targeting_table.setCellWidget(row_count, 2, loot_combo_box)

        only_if_killed_combo_box = QComboBox()
        only_if_killed_combo_box.addItems(["Yes", "No"])
        self.targeting_table.setCellWidget(row_count, 3, only_if_killed_combo_box)

    def delete_creature_button_clicked(self):

        # Shows the  number of delected rows bellow
        rows = sorted(set(index.row() for index in self.targeting_table.selectedIndexes()))
        # Removing the selected rows, if nothing is selected nothing happens
        i = 0
        for index in sorted(rows):
            self.targeting_table.removeRow(index + i)
            i = i - 1
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create the Qt Application
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    # Create and show the form
    form = MainWindow()
    form.show()
        # Run the main Qt loop
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

With this when pressing the "load" button I get this result:
{'None': {'danger': 'None', 'loot': 'None', 'only_if_trapped': 'None'}}
If I change the way of obtaining the values from the Qtable the best I get is QlineEdit, but I can not get the Spinbox or the combobox values

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Updated the OP.

Comment: No, the MRE that is an important part of your post should not depend on an external link since if it breaks it will make your post useless

Comment: SO does not allow me to post the full working code (even though i cut out a lot). It tells me that the code is too long and that my comment is too short. @Edit  it went through

Comment: If your code is too long then it is not an MRE. An MRE is not equivalent to the code of your project (remember that in SO we do not help you in your project but in a specific problem), if your project is small (it has few lines of code) then it could be an MRE, but if it is not then you will have to work to remove the irrelevant parts for your current question.

Comment: 1) An MRE must show the imports, 2) Since in python the indentations in your MRE must also be important so I recommend correcting it

Comment: I think it is a 1 specific problem, I can change the QSpinBox and QCombox to QLineEdits and I will get the date, but I would rather keep the other widgets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The widgets placed above the view have nothing to do with the model, they are independent, so you should not use the model but rather the cellWidget() method to obtain the corresponding widget and through the widget obtain the information.

```py
targeting_table_content = []

for row in range(self.targeting_table.rowCount()):
    name = self.targeting_table.item(row, 0).text()
    danger = self.targeting_table.cellWidget(row, 1).value()
    loot = self.targeting_table.cellWidget(row, 2).currentText()
    only_if_trapped = self.targeting_table.cellWidget(row, 3).currentText()
    targeting_table_content.append(
        {
            "name": name,
            "danger": danger,
            "loot": loot,
            "only_if_trapped": only_if_trapped,
        }
    )
print(targeting_table_content)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have the same solution in other parts of the program but somehow didn't think of using it here